# How to enable multiple files with Serilog RollingFile sink?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, serilog

I've setup my sink as follows:

```
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "RollingFile",
    "Args": {
      "pathFormat": "log-{Date}.log",
      "fileSizeLimitBytes": 20000000,
    }
  }
]
```

My understanding was that once the `log-06042019.log` file reaches 20000000 bytes, it will start logging to `log-06042019-001.log`, then to `log-06042019-002.log` and so on.

But that doesn't happen.  It simply stops logging until the next day.
Am I missing something simple in order to enable the rolling characteristics of this sink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use the RollingFile sink anymore. Instead, use the [File Sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file).

The file sink has a setting to roll over at a certain size. Here's the C# configuration:

```
.WriteTo.File("log.txt", rollOnFileSizeLimit: true)
```

or appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "File", "Args": { "path": "log.txt", "rollOnFileSizeLimit": "true" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I am planning to.  Is the `rollOnFileSizeLimit` feature available for the RollingFile meanwhile - so that I can update it.

Comment: @AngryHacker Why not try it and find out? Or just swap it out for the correct sink?

Comment: I am going to try it - thought you might know off the top of your head.

Comment: @AngryHacker Nope, I don't know off the top of my head. I tend to ignore the file sinks in favor of logging to [Seq](https://datalust.co/seq). It's far easier to have you logs in a centralized location with a simple yet powerful ability to filter the data down to just what you're looking for.